# Align the numbers on their decimal point

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

[image]

I would like to align the numbers on their decimal point. I used the following code for my table:

```latex
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|cccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Variable}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Mean } & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Standard Deviation}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Skewness} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{Kurtosis} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{a} &     6.23 &   1.89 &   0.65 & 2.00 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} &   25.74 & 14.84 &   0.85 & 2.73 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c} &   30.94 & 17.05 &   0.00 & 1.96 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{d} &   42.88 & 15.40 &   0.78 & 3.15 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} &   30.14 & 14.39 &   1.39 & 4.28 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{f} &   23.03 & 14.26 &   1.84 & 6.13 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{g} &   51.67 & 17.66 &  -0.29 & 2.30 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{h} &   41.48 & 19.96 &   0.70 & 2.66 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{i} &   52.89 & 23.54 &  -0.36 & 2.33 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{j} &   40.23 & 20.99 &   0.01 & 2.03 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{k} &  46.38 & 16.54 &   1.03 & 3.02 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{l} & 100.09 &   1.05 &  -1.35 & 6.44 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{m} &  99.57 &   1.36 &  -0.45 & 2.06 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several redundancies in your code. The two columns before `|` are not used; also `\multirow` seems completely unnecessary. Empty rows are not the best way to add vertical spacing (which doesn't seem good, by the way).

Use `S` from `siunitx`, specifying the column format.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\caption{Add caption}\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
}
\toprule
Variable & {Mean} & {Standard Deviation} & {Skewness} & {Kurtosis} \\
\midrule
a &   6.23 &  1.89 &  0.65 & 2.00 \\
b &  25.74 & 14.84 &  0.85 & 2.73 \\
c &  30.94 & 17.05 &  0.00 & 1.96 \\
d &  42.88 & 15.40 &  0.78 & 3.15 \\
e &  30.14 & 14.39 &  1.39 & 4.28 \\
f &  23.03 & 14.26 &  1.84 & 6.13 \\
g &  51.67 & 17.66 & -0.29 & 2.30 \\
h &  41.48 & 19.96 &  0.70 & 2.66 \\
i &  52.89 & 23.54 & -0.36 & 2.33 \\
j &  40.23 & 20.99 &  0.01 & 2.03 \\
k &  46.38 & 16.54 &  1.03 & 3.02 \\
l & 100.09 &  1.05 & -1.35 & 6.44 \\
m &  99.57 &  1.36 & -0.45 & 2.06 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I propose this variant, based on `siunitx`. I loaded `caption` to have a correct spacing between caption and table. normally, rules from booktabs shouldn't be used with vertical rules, due the padding around the horizontal rules. However, a single thicker vertical grey rule is acceptable (to my eyes). I didn't use `multirow, replacing it with`\setcellgapes`from`makecell`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs, multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]%
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{c!{\color{LightGrey!80}\vline width 2.5pt}S[table-format=3.2]S S[table-format=-1.2]S}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Variable} & {Mean} & {\makecell{Standard\\ Deviation}} & {Skewness} & {Kurtosis} \\
\midrule
a & 6.23 & 1.89 & 0.65 & 2.00 \\
b & 25.74 & 14.84 & 0.85 & 2.73 \\
c & 30.94 & 17.05 & 0.00 & 1.96 \\
d & 42.88 & 15.40 & 0.78 & 3.15 \\
e & 30.14 & 14.39 & 1.39 & 4.28 \\
f & 23.03 & 14.26 & 1.84 & 6.13 \\
g & 51.67 & 17.66 & -0.29 & 2.30 \\
h & 41.48 & 19.96 & 0.70 & 2.66 \\
i & 52.89 & 23.54 & -0.36 & 2.33 \\
j & 40.23 & 20.99 & 0.01 & 2.03 \\
k & 46.38 & 16.54 & 1.03 & 3.02 \\
l & 100.09 & 1.05 & -1.35 & 6.44 \\
m & 99.57 & 1.36 & -0.45 & 2.06 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have also other tables and for all tables their numbers should be aligned on their decimal points. Is it possible to have this feature for all tables in general? thank you

Comment: You have to use the `S` column type for that.

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work for me. When i know how many S i have to replace for c?

Comment: As many as columns with numbers having to be aligned. However, remember that a cell in an `S` column may have non-aligned content (e.g. the column head). In this case, put the content between a pair of braces, so it be centred.

Comment: +1. Nice touch to split "standard deviation" across two lines, making the column widths much more even. However, I think the table would look better *without* the `!{\color{LightGrey!80}\vline width 2.5pt}` bit... Naturally, though, there's no accounting for taste, is there? :-)

Comment: @Mico: Matter of personal taste… (actually I'd prefer to have all lines grey, but I thought it would make things needlessly complex).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is the purpose to use `\multirow` in this table! Hope the below modified tag may suits with you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow,dcolumn,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}%

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cc|d{3,2}d{2,2}d{2,2}d{1,2}}
    \toprule
    Variable & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Standard Deviation} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Skewness} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Kurtosis} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{a} &     6.23 &   1.89 &   0.65 & 2.00 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} &   25.74 & 14.84 &   0.85 & 2.73 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c} &   30.94 & 17.05 &   0.00 & 1.96 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{d} &   42.88 & 15.40 &   0.78 & 3.15 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} &   30.14 & 14.39 &   1.39 & 4.28 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{f} &   23.03 & 14.26 &   1.84 & 6.13 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{g} &   51.67 & 17.66 &  -0.29 & 2.30 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{h} &   41.48 & 19.96 &   0.70 & 2.66 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{i} &   52.89 & 23.54 &  -0.36 & 2.33 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{j} &   40.23 & 20.99 &   0.01 & 2.03 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{k} &  46.38 & 16.54 &   1.03 & 3.02 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{l} & 100.09 &   1.05 &  -1.35 & 6.44 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{m} &  99.57 &   1.36 &  -0.45 & 2.06 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE is not complete. I had to add the `booktabs` package and the `multirow` package.

Here, the solution is to use the `S` column (from the `siunitx` package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{cc|SSSS}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Variable}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Mean}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Standard Deviation}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Skewness}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Kurtosis}} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{a} &     6.23 &   1.89 &   0.65 & 2.00 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b} &   25.74 & 14.84 &   0.85 & 2.73 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c} &   30.94 & 17.05 &   0.00 & 1.96 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{d} &   42.88 & 15.40 &   0.78 & 3.15 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{e} &   30.14 & 14.39 &   1.39 & 4.28 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{f} &   23.03 & 14.26 &   1.84 & 6.13 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{g} &   51.67 & 17.66 &  -0.29 & 2.30 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{h} &   41.48 & 19.96 &   0.70 & 2.66 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{i} &   52.89 & 23.54 &  -0.36 & 2.33 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{j} &   40.23 & 20.99 &   0.01 & 2.03 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{k} &  46.38 & 16.54 &   1.03 & 3.02 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{l} & 100.09 &   1.05 &  -1.35 & 6.44 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{m} &  99.57 &   1.36 &  -0.45 & 2.06 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]